# uname -n vs hostname

Tags: hostname, posix

What is the difference between `uname -n` and `hostname`? Are there any real differences in what they return? Are there any differences in availability on different OSes?  Is one of them included in POSIX and the other not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference. `hostname` and `uname -n` output the same information. They both obtain it from the `uname()` system call.

One difference is that the `hostname` command can be used to *set* the hostname as well as getting it. `uname` cannot do that. (Normally this is done only once, early in the boot process!)

Comment: What about POSIX and availability?  Will both of these be present everywhere?

Comment: Don't know. I have a feeling that `uname` has a SysV heritage and `hostname` a BSD heritage but I don't know what POSIX says.

Answer (score 5):

Like others have said, `uname -n` is your friend, and has an advantage in that it is a POSIX/SUSv4-compliant command, whereas `hostname` is not.

Note that, however, `uname -n` is a simple wrapper around the `gethostname(2)` system call.  In particular, it does not consult the name service to convert the name returned by `gethostname(2)` into a fully-qualified domain name, which can be achieved by `hostname -f` on Linux.  (BSD/Apple `hostname -f` is identical to `uname -n`.)

Answer (score 0):

- uname (**u**nix **name**) prints system information.
- The `uname -n` is same as `hostname`.
- Both uses in background uname() system call.